# addEventListener worked only for the first time

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am using $.post to load the registration form, below is the code that is loaded, after that this page uses XMLhtppRequest() to send form data and return response on the same page,

everything is working perfect whenever the register button is clicked for the first time, but if i want to resubmit the form again in case there is any validation errors, the script won't work and the whole page reloaded.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<button type="submit" id="register">Register</button>
</form>
<script>
var handleRegisterationProcess = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //console.log($("input.email").val());
    var data = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("register"));
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'url here');
    request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        $('selector here').html(request.responseText).show();
    }
};    
};

var register = document.getElementById('register');
register.addEventListener('click', handleRegisterationProcess);    
</script>
```

Comment: @adeneo Do you mean i have to use Jquery instead?

Comment: @ahmedsaber111 no, you don't have to use jquery at all, but if you do. Be _consistent_ with the way you use it, try to avoid mixing vanilla js listeners and random jquery calls here and there. Also, comment of adeneo implies that you have jQuery used within your code, but not tagged to the question. **Can it be used?** is the question.

Comment: @ahmedsaber111 - it looks like you're already using jQuery, so you're either using too much, or not enough jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Are you replacing your #register button with a new one from the ajax response? If so then the new button will not have the event attached.

If this is the case then maybe try to attach the event again in the ajax readystate callback

Comment: the whole form including the script itself is replaced when the submit button pressed, but the same button reloaded again, do i have to re attach the event again

Comment: the same issue that the page didn't listen for the click event in the second time i clicked the button

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
$('selector here').html(request.responseText).show();
```

You are replacing your email form with new form via `jQuery` `html` method and handlers still available only for old(replaced) form. Try `jQuery` event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#register', handleRegisterationProcess);
```

Comment: `$(".registerForm").delegate("#register", "click", handleRegisterationProcess);` I am tried this code and it worked very nice with me but then i faced another issue, that i can't save values from the form else the first submitted value

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, in the case you're replacing the whole form, is this:

```
if (request.readyState === 4) {
    $('selector here').html(request.responseText).show();
    var register = document.getElementById('register');
    register.addEventListener('click', handleRegisterationProcess);
}
```

yes... reattaching the handler.

Comment: I am tried this now, but the same issue that the page didn't listen for the click event in the second time i clicked the button

Comment: What's the selector you're using? Or what exactly are you replacing? Have you tried using the `submit` event of the form?

Comment: `$('.jqimessage').html(request.responseText).show();` jqimessage is the container that wrapping the form and script, also i don't tried the submit event, could it make sense

Comment: uh... if it wraps the form AND the script, then you first need to move that script out of there! That might explain why no other solution has worked so far, jQuery won't evaluate the script tag.

Comment: so how could i separate the form from the script

Comment: Well for that we would need to know a bit more about your architecture, but based on what I know at the moment, just moving it outside of the `.jqimessage` container will make it static (in this case), that way you could register the event again and the function will actually exist.

Comment: I would ask another question, why when i am using the delegation event `$(".registerForm").delegate("#register", "click", handleRegisterationProcess);` it worked very nice with me but then i faced another issue, that i can't save values from the form else the first submitted values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers, all of them were helpful for me :), the issue was made by my mistake, in the below line of code

```
$('.jqimessage').html(request.responseText).show();
```

I have multiple selectors with the same class name in the page, so my form and script always placed about four times in the page every time i submit the page, this made a conflict in the JS script.

I replaced my selector like below

```
$('#jqistate_state2 .jqimessage').html(request.responseText).show();
```